# Google Maps API V3 removing a marker

Tags: google-maps

I am converting a web page from Google Maps API v2 to 3 in V2 I could do the below to remove a marker -

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "singlerightclick", function(pixel,tile, marker) {
 if(marker){
  if (confirm("Deselect " + marker.title +" and remove from Map?")){
   map.removeOverlay(marker);
    window.status = "Deselected>" + marker.title + "<" ;}}
  });
```

However I have now changed the code  to add markers and cannot figure out how to select the right mouse clicked on marker from the markerarray, I am using the following code to add a marker

```
function createRedMarker(Lat,Lang,html,atitle) { 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng, 
     map: map,
     title: atitle,
     icon:redmarker,
shadow:mshadow
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {infowindow.setContent(html); infowindow.open(map,marker);});     
markersArray.push(marker); 
    }
```

Would it be possible for someone to give me some pointers on how to do this

Comment: Can you post a link to live code?  Or put your code on JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another event listener for the rightclick, below the first event listener.  So your code will look like this:

```
...
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {infowindow.setContent(html); infowindow.open(map,marker);});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function() {
if (confirm("Deselect " + marker.title +" and remove from Map?")){
   marker.setMap(null);
    window.status = "Deselected>" + marker.title + "<" ;}}
});
markersArray.push(marker); 
...
```